# PHP output on different page

Tags: php, redirect

For a search-functionality on my page, I´ve got a submit that gives a title to a php via `GET`. 
After the submit, I get to the called php. What I need is, that I get to a different site where I can see the result of the called php-function.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Your question seems to be a little obscure. Maybe just keep the information in session and restore it with a GET will do the job (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: i think you are talking about the referer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question. But if you need to redirect from one page to another and retain some information, you can save information to the session and restore it after the redirect has finnished.

```
<?php
# search.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['searchresult'] = 'Hello World';
header('Location: /result.php');
exit;
?>

<?php
# result.php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['searchresult'])) echo $_SESSION['searchresult'];
unset($_SESSION['searchresult']);
?>
```

Comment: he said `different site`, so I guess the session won't work here.

Comment: I wasn't sure if by site he meant actually a site or just simply a web page. If it was indeed a differenct site he meant, your example code is spot on, I must say. Another way would be to send a server side request or set up session sharing.

Answer (score 1):

**If the websites are different, you can't use sessions.**

Here is a very simple (unsecure) example to illustrate how to forward the result via a GET parameter to the other website.

The page called by the submit:

```
<?php
# search.php
$searchedTitle = $_GET['title'];
// Perform the search, and finds $result
// ...
$result = search($searchedTitle);
// Redirect to the other website, and forward the result as a GET parameter
header('Location: www.otherwebsite.com/result.php?result=' . urlencode($result));
exit;
```

On the other website:

```
<?php
# www.otherwebsite.com/result.php
$result = $_GET['result'];
```

This will work if the `$result` variable contains a simple data (short string). If that's a large array, you should use a POST parameter instead of a GET.